# Android FB login app - invalid key hash

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I have this problem, I create FB login with FB SDK Android with java in Eclipse. When i debug and run this app in Android Emulator all is correct, i can login i can logout. But when i export app to develop version (.apk), and install it at my phone or at genymotion emulator i geting this errors:

```
"Invlaid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/72012084472886"
```

The hash key is create correoct i use this:

```
 try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Do you have some idea, what is wrong?

Thank you .

Comment: follow this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks, but i follow this instruction when i create my app...

Comment: Release Apk is using different key for signing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an app via ADB Eclipse usually uses a keystore named `debug.keystore`, this keystore is usually the one you don't use on production apps. When you export your app and create a keystore, the keyhash will change value because you change keystore.

You can implement this code to your app so you can echo the keyhash to you stackrace:

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageInfo(pContext, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        }
    }
```

The snippet is only suitable for development, not for production!